# Convert csv to json according to the requirements

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

so given the csv files with the given tables:

marks:

```
test_id  student_id  mark
     1           1    78
     2           1    87
     3           1    95
     4           1    32
     5           1    65
     6           1    78
     7           1    40
     1           2    78
     2           2    87
     3           2    15
     6           2    78
     7           2    40
     1           3    78
     2           3    87
     3           3    95
     4           3    32
     5           3    65
     6           3    78
     7           3    40
```

course :

```
   id name
   1    A
   2    B
   3    C
```

tests:

```
  id  course_id  weight
   1          1      10
   2          1      40
   3          1      50
   4          2      40
   5          2      60
   6          3      90
   7          3      10
```

students:

```
  id name
   1    A
   2    B
   3    C
```

note: weight: how much of the student’s final grade the test is worth. For example, if a test is worth 50, that means that this test is worth 50% of the final grade for this course.

need to convert them to json in this format:

```html
{
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A",
      "totalAverage": 72.03,
      "courses": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Biology",
          "teacher": "Mr. D",
          "courseAverage": 90.1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Math",
          "teacher": "Mrs. C",
          "courseAverage": 74.2
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "History",
          "teacher": "Mrs. P",
          "courseAverage": 51.8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "totalAverage": 62.15,
      "courses": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Biology",
          "teacher": "Mr. D",
          "courseAverage": 50.1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Math",
          "teacher": "Mrs. C",
          "courseAverage": 74.2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "C",
      "totalAverage": 72.03,
      "courses": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Biology",
          "teacher": "Mr. D",
          "courseAverage": 90.1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "History",
          "teacher": "Mrs. P",
          "courseAverage": 51.8
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Math",
          "teacher": "Mrs. C",
          "courseAverage": 74.2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

new to this type of problem so looking for how to get values from different tables to calculate courseAverage and also the totalAverage. also looking for how to put it accordingly in json

Comment: You will get better help here if you include these 4 tables as text to your question. Also, show your current attempt. The problem looks a lot like homework and while we can help, we are not a homework-writing service

Comment: added the tables and its not a homework

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty typical of as data processing workload: combine data from various sources, perform some calculations and output the result in a defined format.

Let's first define the input dataframes:

```py
from io import StringIO

marks = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
test_id  student_id  mark
     1           1    78
     2           1    87
     3           1    95
     4           1    32
     5           1    65
     6           1    78
     7           1    40
     1           2    78
     2           2    87
     3           2    15
     6           2    78
     7           2    40
     1           3    78
     2           3    87
     3           3    95
     4           3    32
     5           3    65
     6           3    78
     7           3    40
'''), sep='\s+')

courses = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
   id name
   1    A
   2    B
   3    C
'''), sep='\s+')

tests = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
  id  course_id  weight
   1          1      10
   2          1      40
   3          1      50
   4          2      40
   5          2      60
   6          3      90
   7          3      10
'''), sep='\s+')

students = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
  id name
   1    A
   2    B
   3    C
'''), sep='\s+')
```

And the processing:

```py
# Combine (aka join or merge) the 4 tables into one
# `id` has different meaning for each table so we will disambiguate
# it by renaming it `student_id`, `course_id`, etc.
combined = (
    students.add_prefix('student_')
        .merge(marks, on='student_id')
        .merge(tests.rename(columns={'id': 'test_id'}), on='test_id')
        .merge(courses.add_prefix('course_'), on='course_id')
)
combined['weighted_mark'] = combined['mark'] * combined['weight'] / 100


# Build a student-course level summary
# You didn't provide a `teacher_name` column in the `courses` dataframe
course_summary = (
    combined.groupby(['student_id', 'student_name', 'course_id', 'course_name'], as_index=False)
        .agg(course_average=('weighted_mark', 'sum'))
)
# Assemble the summary into a dictionary
course_summary['course'] = course_summary.apply(lambda row: {
    'id': row['course_id'],
    'name': row['course_name'],
    'courseAverage': round(row['course_average'], 1)
}, axis=1)


# Build a student-level summary
student_summary = (
    course_summary.groupby(['student_id', 'student_name'], as_index=False)
        .agg(
            # Aggregate all courses taken by each student into a list
            courses=('course', lambda c: list(c)),
            # Student's average is the mean of all course averages
            total_average=('course_average', 'mean')
        )
)
# Assemble the summary into a dictionary
student_summary['student'] = student_summary.apply(lambda row: {
    'id': row['student_id'],
    'name': row['student_name'],
    'totalAverage': round(row['total_average'], 2),
    'courses': row['courses']
}, axis=1)


# The final output:
import json
with open('output.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump({
        'students': student_summary['student'].to_list()
    }, fp, indent=2)
```